# What do you know about 3 Zero (0-development 0-deployment 0-management) Concepts?

Tags: deployment

I heard about this 3 zero-* concept some time ago, and like the idea very much.  Now I want to become more familiar with the concept, as well as locate the source.

Neither Google nor fellow developers could provide any additional details.

What do you know about the 3 zero-* concept?

Comment: Sorry for stepping on your toes Gortok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term was coined in Ted Neward's book ["Server-based Java Programming"](http://www.amazon.ca/Server-Based-Java-Programming-Ted-Neward/dp/1884777716).